# How to show dialog from other class

Tags: java, android

I try to make Dialog from Android documentation

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

below we can read something like this:

> Now, when you create an instance of this class and call show() on that
>   object, the dialog appears as shown in figure 1.

BUT, when I try create a dialog from my main activity:

```
FireMissilesDialogFragment myDialog = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
            myDialog.???
```

I don't have method `show()` on myDialog :|

What is wrong ?

Comment: Click on the [`show()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html#show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String)) link in the documentation. It will take you to docs for that method, where you will see which arguments are necessary; i.e., a `FragmentManager`, and a `String` tag. For example, `myDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in your Main Activity:

```
new FireMissilesDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

is for showing your dialog